# If an IoC container is not a Service Locator, then what's the point of it?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

I am currently learning about DI and IoC containers to see if my application may benefit from using them.
At first I thought I understood what they are good for (namely to get instances of interfaces in a decoupled way), but then I read a blog post about [common mistakes with IoC containers](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/how-not-to-do-dependency-injection-the-static-or-singleton-container). After thinking about this for some time there seems to be no benefit at all if you use the container just at the very beginning of an application.

If I were to implement this pattern in my current application I would just end up replacing code like

```
IFoo foo = new Foo();
IBar bar = new Bar(foo);
```

with

```
container.Register<IFoo, Foo>();
container.Register<IBar, Bar>();
bar = container.GetInstance<IBar>();
```

in my initialization routines.

In my opinion that would neither improve readability nor decoupling but just complicate my code.

Obviously that can't be true, because otherwise it wouldn't be such a big deal. So what am I missing?

**Update**:
My real question is the following: Is it true that the IoC container should only be used in the composition root?

If that is the case I really don't see the point, because I already have such a function where all main objects are created and the benefit of obscuring `new` calls seems to be really small.

Additionally I would like to know why many DI frameworks support things like scope, when they should only be used in one place (and not in my business logic where they would make sense)?

Comment: With only one `GetInstance` call you should be able to create your whole application object graph. An Ideal application will have only one `GetInstance` call (or only at [CompositionRoot](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/)).

Comment: That may be true, but what's the point of having only one `GetInstance` call if you need a lot of `Register` calls beforehand. It looks like the problem is just moved slightly and it is still equally complicated if not more to create the object graph.

Comment: @Karsten: If you make every mapping explicitly, the use of a DI library is limited (although you could still benefit from auto-wiring), but DI libraries get really beneficial when you use batch-registration and convention over configuration. See [this article](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/11/06/WhentouseaDIContainer/).

Comment: Benefit is you can swap the implementations in one line of code. If you want to create a lot of `Bar` instances you don't need the boiler plate code to create Foo, then Bar in all those places. IOC containers will get their hands dirty, etc. Also remember there is Convention over configuration support available in containers, so that you don't need to explicitly register.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you're confusing two things.  The IoC container, and the IoC (or rather, dependency injection) pattern.

Dependency Injection is a form of Inversion of Control, but all IoC is not DI.  DI is a design pattern, in which dependencies are injected into your classes rather than your classes creating these dependencies themselves.

You don't need a DI container to do DI.  Although a container provides a lot of nice functionality once your application is designed to use DI.  So yes, a DI container is a service locator, or perhaps even a generic factory.

When people say that Service Location is bad, or that its an anti-pattern, they mean that using the Service Location pattern in your application everywhere you need an instance of something is bad.  This creates dependencies throughout your app on concrete instances.  Even if you're using interfaces with service locator, you're still forcing your components to choose which dependencies to create.  That has repercussions when it comes time to do unit testing, since you can no longer pass Mock or "Dummy" instances to your objects, since they are now hard coded into your classes instantiation.

The point of DI is that a class doesn't know what specific instance of an object it is working with, so you can pass it anything.  This could be a real instance, a test instance, an instance specific to your user, an instance specific to the environment, etc... All the object knows is that it has an interface to make a call to get what it wants.

Surely you can understand how convenient it would be to be able to swap out dependencies whenever you want without having to alter the code of the objects themselves?

Yes, it's true that configuring your DI in a composition root can add more complexity to the configuration, but it is the act of segregating your dependencies into interfaces that makes them more flexible and reduces dependencies within the application.

Different kinds of apps benefit differently from DI.

In addition to all the benefits of DI, DI Containers provide a huge benefit in terms of object lifetime management.  For instance, in a web application, you can configure it to provide unique instances of dependencies per web request, or even per user or session.  And have it destroy those instances once the request or session ends.  You don't have to pass objects down the graph either.  Let's say you use an object at the top of your object graph, and need it again 10 calls down.  You don't need to make it global, or pass it through all the objects that don't need it.

DI is one of those things that you just have to trust in at first, and the more you use it, the more you grow to appreciate it.

So what makes using a DI Container "good" is that you are doing all of your "service location" in one place.  Then, you are building your object graph and using that via injection afterwards.  You can't get away from the fact that dependencies have to be created, and whether or not it's through service location or straight up "new" those dependencies have to exist.  But by putting them in one place, you are reducing the complexity of the rest of the application.

Is it a shell game?  In a way.  But the benefits are very real.

EDIT:

Imagine this:

```
public class Foo : IFoo {
    public Foo(IBar bar) {}
}

public class Bar : IBar {
    public Bar(IBaz baz) {}
}

public class Baz : IBaz {
    public Baz(IFooBar fooBar) {}
}

.... etc..
```

Now, if you want to create a new IFoo, you have to do this:

```
IFoo = new Foo(new Bar(new Baz(new FooBar(... etc...))));
```

And, this could get quite complicated.  However, with a DI Container, you need only register all your interfaces, and the DI Container will now create all those other instances.

```
IFoo = kernel.Get<IFoo>(); // or whatever your DI container uses to get the service
```

It automatically creates all dependent instances, as you've configured them with the given lifestyles you've configured them with (singleton, per request, transient, custom, etc..).  So if IBaz is configured to be a singleton, then it will create new instances of Foo and Bar, but reuse the same instance of Baz wherever you need it.

As I said, DI Containers are not required for DI, but they do provide a lot of really nice functionality, which you will grow to like the more you use it.

Comment: To clarify: I am not confusing DI and IoC. I understand what DI is and already used it successfully. I was just wondering how IoC containers are supposed to be used.

Comment: @Karsten - Saying `IFoo foo = new Foo()` only instantiates Foo, it doesn't walk the chain of dependencies and instantiate the dependencies Foo depends on, and the dependencies foo's dependencies depend on, etc.. etc..  IoC containers do.

Answer (score 1):

Like every tool and pattern it is best used when there is a need for them. The DI-pattern is great because it makes unit testing easier, since instead of depending on a specific class you depend on an interface. When unit testing a class the injected interface can be replaced with a mock object that behaves exactly as desired.

IoC-containers are used for object creation management. Together with the DI-pattern this allows you to specify in one location how objects are created. The opposite where objects are created throughout your code can be a pain if you for instance later change how your object is created. You then need to go to each location to change. With an IoC-container the change is required in one place only.

On top of that if you follow the DI-pattern for all your classes, using an IoC-containers GetInstance will cascade the creation of all objects needed for the specific task and only one GetInstance call is needed.

Comment: Very usefull to mention that code later need to changes and need to be tested.

Answer (score 0):

A container is a service locator just as you showed in your example.

However, many applications are typically using a framework such as ASP.NET MVC which hides the service location. Instead you use constructor injection in your classes to get their dependencies injected.

If you are not using a library/framework, you are typically just using service location for the root classes in your project. All other classes are get their dependencies through constructor injection.

As your example is quite trivial it doesn't illustrate that. So yes, a minimal example do get more complex, while real world applications get less complexity.

You are also forgetting that IoC containers can also handle different lifetimes. In an HTTP application it means that a lot of requests can run in parallel without getting threading issues as each request get it's own container scope. That too reduced complexity.

Answer (score 0):

**Because of Hollywood principle**, with Service locator, **a class ask for an instance** of another class, and could potentially ask also for instances of other classes, a programmer may be temptated to ask instances to save time in the immediate or just because don't see potential problems. Later the maintainers have to debug strange behaviours because the could not imagine that a class was working on certain instances (same as using global variables but more subtle and harder to find).

> Don't call us...

A IoC container would create objects and **pass correct instances** into object constructors

> ... we'll call you

Effectively it is the container creating the instance and giving it to the class, and is not the class calling any method to do that, that alleviates the class from at least 1 responsability (get the instance in some way).

This decouple "the way" in wich the instance is get. In complex projects passing instances around force to write extra code (just see implementation of certain opensource 3d engines like Irrlicht) that could quickly become a mess, the IoC container take that code away once and forever reducing the complexity.

Note that, with a service locator, the class must at least call 1 "getInstance" method. With IoC container, you get rid of that call too.